# Add trailing zeroes to line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file containing (hundreds) of blocks of numbers like below;

This one is fine (16x20, correct number of rows and columns)

```
11111111111111111110
16666616666666661110
16111616111111162610
16111646111663132610
16162616261623132610
16162313261623132610
16162313261623132610
16162313261623132610
16162313261623132610
16162313261623132610
16162313261623132610
16162313261626132610
16166313661116632610
16111111111116132610
16666666666666136610
11111111111111111110
```

This one needs to be padded with trailing zeroes so it is (16x20)

```
111111111111111111
166616666666663661
166611111111111661
166666366663661661
113161111111161611
1316166666616161
1616162262616161
11616166112616161
16616166116616161
16616162262616161
16616166266616161
16616111161116161
1661666666666616111
1661666166163366661
1641666166166613661
1111111111111111111
```

I would like to pad them with zeroes so they are all like the first example. I'm aware of the regular expressions feature in notepad++ but am struggling to get it to work. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: a better editor will do it easily... notepad++...  good luck!

Comment: Could you recommend another editor and technique to do this? I'm not tied to notepad++ or anything just thought I could accomplish this little task in it.

Comment: I added an answer with vim/gvim editor. if you thought the answer is not appropriated here, I am gonna remove it. hope it helps

Comment: also, if you file is very big, like you said, 1400+ blocks, you may consider some text processors, like awk, sed. it would be a piece of cake for those tool. e.g. `awk 'length<20{for(i=length;i<=20;i++)$0=$0"0"}1' file` will finish the job in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it via a macro.

First append a large number of zeroes to the end of each line using a macro.

1. Caret on the first entry
2. click record macro
3. press `end`
4. type out 20 zeroes
5. press `down arrow`
6. click stop recording
7. play the macro until all lines look like this

   11111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   16661666666666366100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   16661111111111166100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   16666636666366166100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   11316111111116161100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   131616666661616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   161616226261616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1161616611261616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1661616611661616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1661616226261616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1661616626661616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1661611116111616100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   166166666666661611100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   166166616616336666100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   164166616616661366100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Then...

1. Caret on first line
2. click record
3. press `home` key
4. press the `right arrow` key 20 times
5. hold `shift` and press `end` key
6. press `delete` key
7. press `down arrow`
8. click stop recording
9. play the macro until all lines are processed

You could save the entire process as a single macro so its just a single click in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a macro solution

go to the beginning of your text

select `Macro/Start Recording`

press <kbd>end</kbd>, press <kbd>0</kbd> 16 times then press <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>down arrow key</kbd>

select `Macro/End Recording`

You now have a macro to add sixteen zeros to the end of all lines.
Playback this macro on all lines.

You now have appended zeroes to all lines.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and using mouse select the required block(columns) of text you want and paste it into another empty  notepad tab

help on column mode editing is there inside notepad `? / help contents` menu

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin ConyEdit to do this.
With ConyEdit running in the background, follow these steps:

1. use the command line `cc.aal 00000000000000000000` to append after lines with twenty zero character.
2. use the command line `cc.gc 1/\d{20}/` to get the first column of regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to do this manualy and not progomaticly ?

Open Findreplace

Copy from  the last to rhe first WITHOUT NUMBERS on a line so...

in this example

111111111111111111 <---from here
to here ---> 166616666666663661
166611111111111661

paste that into the fine ( yes your effecticly copying the return wich some applications allow you to manualy input others wont )

then in the replace box,  type   '0' then your return
Hit that magic replace all :D

This will then add a 0 every time it hits a new line,  then add a new... new line....

edit : quickly reviewing another method a second to recover for alternate options :P give me 10

edit 2:

Ah ok somthing like this will work :P just tested it.
use [0-9] in the find replace.  so if im looking for 123123123123 ( wich is 12 long ) and i need to buff i up to 20,
Your FIND must be in  ()
so..

the find would be

```
 ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]  )
```

and the replace is referd to as \1 no the regex,  this was my mistake

\100000000

tested and confirmed !dont forget YOU NEED MATCH ALL **on**,  WRAP **off**!

And so on for your other numbers,  Not sure if you can loop this with macros nd stuff :P but hope it helps more than you have now

two good resources.

http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/comment-page-1/

http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Please improve the spelling of this answer.

Comment: Doing this manually is not feasible I have ~1400 of these blocks to process so would much rather a regular expression or macro if possible, thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: a 2nd update.  but tested and confirmed with your data.  Its still a litle work but ALOT faster

Answer (score 0):

base on OP's comment: you could try an editor called vim/gvim

open your file in vim, then type:

```
:%s/.*/\=printf("%-20s",getline("."))/|%s/ *$/\=substitute(submatch(0)," ","0","g")/
```

don't forget pressing `<Enter>` after the above typing.

then you will see the text has been changed into what you want.

of course vim macro can work as well, however, I feel command better... :)